# Token not clearing properly while single sign out in Kentor

Tags: logout, kentor-authservices

We are implementing SSO with kentor using HTTP module. Our SP is ADFS.
In the ADFS we configured  "Transform an Incoming claim" with Incoming claim type as "E-mail Address", OutgoingClaimType as NameID and OutGoing NameId format as "Email". When we logout from the application using("~/AuthServices/Logout?ReturnUrl=~/?Status=LoggedOut") it is redirecting to ADFS Signout  page(https://win-3obaenpbsol.dc10.inapp.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0).
and when we try load our application again, It redirect into the application with out asking the login. So the expected result is once we logout it should ask the login again how can we handle this?

Thanks,
Raj
.

Comment: did you realize how to do that?